# exclude a post from wp_query loop

Tags: wp-query

0 down vote favorite

I show my last post in a page with this code:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query();
$query1->the_post();
```

and it further with:

```
$id = $query->ID;
```

to retrieve last post ID so I wrote a new wp_query and I want to exclue that ID from the results: I wrote this but it don't work:

```
$query2-> new WP_Query('p=-$id');
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your specific question (and posted code) correctly, you're actually trying to exclude the **most recent** post from your query? If so, there's a *much* easier method: [use the `offset` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

```
$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 'offset' => 1 ) );
```

Using this method, you exclude the most recent post from `$query2`, and never actually need to run `$query1`.

Answer (score 4):

Change your `Query` to

```
$query2-> new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => array($id) ) );
```

This is the right parameter.

Comment: If you just want to exclude a Post, do the above. `p` is if you want to specifically target one post.